# Get size of Bitmap Android

Tags: android, bitmap, get, size, bitmapfactory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bitmap byte-size after decoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407565/bitmap-byte-size-after-decoding)

Is there anyway so I can get the size of this Bitmap?I've tried to use getByteCount() but I can't use it?

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decryptedData , 0, decryptedData .length);    //decoding bytearrayoutputstream to bitmap
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @stema, @ ThiefMaster ; I think, when you close a question as duplicate, then in comment of that question, you should give the link of the original question of which it is a duplicate, so that, others who are searching answer to questions like this, will get benefit from it.

Answer (score 5):

As you can see from the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html), you can use

```
getWidth()
getHeight()
```

for the size of the Bitmap in pixels.

And if it is an array of bytes (8bit = 1byte) then just take `decryptedData.length - offset` and you know how many bytes are in the Bitmap.

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

If the image is locally stored you can do the following

```
public long getImageLength(String absFileName)
{        
    File file = new File(absFileName);
    return file.length();
}

/**
 * From "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically"
 * uri - data stored in an Intent returned from an application such as Gallery or Camera
 */
private String getAbsPath(Uri uri) 
{
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: This is not correct! file size has nothing to do with bitmap size.
Most pics are compressed, and the actual bitmap size is usually bigger.

Comment: what is managedQuery?