# Get Bitmap size after encoding?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Is this right to get Bitmap size after encoding?
what if I need to use it before encoding when select image?

```
if (v == buttonUpload) {
        if (bitmap.getByteCount() > 1000000) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "please check image size!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            uploadImage();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you consider the size? Is you select an image then i think you select an image file by Gallery app. So then file size. You give not enough info to help you.

Comment: Yes this condition after selecting image from Gallery and when he click on upload button to upload image this condition will work to see bitmap size but sometimes won't work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the size of a compressed bitmap image please use:

```
file.length();
```

Comment: So I have to convert bitmap image to integer.

Comment: Nonsense. Bitmaps cannot be converted to integers.

Comment: No need for converting, because you can get the file length with this method. If you check it by using byteCount-method or sizeOf-method, the memory will always be the same, since the used memory is not the same as the actual filesize of bitmap-files.

Comment: Bitmap-files ? Never heard of in an Android context. Please give an example.

Comment: File file = new File(absFileName);
file.length();

As answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833909/get-size-of-bitmap-android

Was using this method and it was working fine.

Comment: More explain please, I'm talking about bitmap only after that was encoded

Comment: `to check the size of a compressed bitmap image please use:

file.length();`. That still is nonsense. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> after encoding

So, after you've saved the bitmap as a PNG or a JPEG? (Using bitmap.compress)

If that's the case, then you can simply get the file and find out it's size using `file.length()` which will give you the byte size of the file (image file, in this case). Look up [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) for more information on working with files.

Or are you trying to figure out the in memory size of the bitmap object? In that case you can use profiling (through DDMS). You can read more about it [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html)