# why image blur after upload android?

Tags: android, image, upload, imageview, blur

I am learning Upload image to server where image taked from gallery or camera android ....

When i show image after take from gallery or camera to imageview with **image decode**, image not blur...
**but after i upload, image like be small size and blurred ..**

I do not know, where is the mistake. whether on the **decoded image** or **upload image**

here part of my code

**decode code**

```
public void decodeFile(String filePath) {
    // Decode image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int scale = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE && height_tmp < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        scale *= 2;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, o2);

    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
```

**upload code**

```
try {

            DatabaseHandler userDB = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());      
            HashMap<String, String> userDetail = userDB.getUserDetails();
            String uid= userDetail.get("uid");  

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();                
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(PHP_URL);               
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data,file_name);              
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile", bab);
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }

            return s.toString().trim();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            err="error"+e.getMessage();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());

            return e.getMessage();
        }
```

**before upload, image show in ImageView**
[image]

**After upload, and show in listview**
[image]

I hope anyone can help me. Sorry if my English is not good ...

Answer (score -1):

[According to method documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) you are compressing image 100 percent which degrades the quality

```
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
```

i suggest using a smaller value than 100 and adjusting till you get a balance between quality and size

Comment: Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small size, **100 meaning compress for max quality**

Comment: Dante and @Selvin , before this... i have set with **bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, bos);** , but it's still blur and smaller...

Comment: yup.. got it wrong, something should be wrong in decoding .. try comparing size of bitmap after download to the one you uploaded

Comment: i don't know how the value of size.. :D

Comment: in listview i use lazyloading , whether because of this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407565/bitmap-byte-size-after-decoding try this